# x2go icon not appearing in dock (20.04)

Tags: virtualbox, icons, 20.04, dock, x2go

Recently upgraded to 20.04.  A small annoyance with x2go client app:  the icon for the remote desktop window (X2GoAgent) doesn't appear in the dock.  It's just a blank square. If I alt-tab, it shows the mini-window, but also no icon.

I presume this is a problem with x2go's interaction with the Ubuntu desktop.  I'm going to try to post a bug with them once I can work out their arcane bug system, but I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone had a quick suggestion or workaround.)

(I also see a similar issue with the VirtualBox machine window.  I wonder this is a general issue with apps that have 'desktop' windows?)

[image]